# How can I remove a Steeple 4 inch axial fan cover?

Tags: bathroom, ceiling-fan

I am trying to get the cover off a Steeple fan that was already installed in my house. Anyone know how please?

[image: mounted fan]

Comment: Most fan covers that have no noticeable screws, are held up with a type of spring.  Usually just pull down and the springs will allow the cover to drop a few inches. Then you can reach in and detach them to remove the cover completely.

Answer (score 2):

Use a small flat-bladed screwdriver to to remove the white plastic plug at 6 o’clock. Then remove the screw behind that with a Philips screwdriver. Slide the panel away from the screw position and off it comes.

Answer (score 2):

Removing the Phillips screw takes a bit of turning, so persevere and it will come off. The screw is held in place by the panel so you can’t lose it.